# How to select the first row for each group (ordering by datetime)?

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

How would I select the first row for each group in MySQL (ordering by datetime)?

I tried and I got to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `cats`
WHERE `war_id` = 0 
AND `eyes_color` = 'green' 
AND `id` IN
    (SELECT `id` FROM
        (SELECT * FROM `cats` ORDER BY `date_last_fought` DESC) AS t
    GROUP BY `war_id`, `n_of_medals`)
```

It kinda works, but I'm not sure if it's the best ever.

Do you think I can simplify this?

Comment: This actually seems to be the best option.  There's not much point in turning it into a join on the same table.  However, you should put `SELECT \`id\`` in the innermost query, and `SELECT *` in any wrapping queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I try to simpilify into this...

```
SELECT * FROM `cats`
inner join (select * from cats 
        WHERE `warid` = 1 AND `color` = 'green' 
        order by orderDate desc) a 
        on (cats.id=a.id)
group by cats.warId;
```

you can see in here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55f5b/5 
but I'm not sure it's better than your query, ...read & act from EXPLAIN still become my homework :D

```
ID  SELECT_TYPE TABLE      TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS    KEY   KEY_LEN   REF    ROWS EXTRA
1   PRIMARY     <derived2> ALL     (null)          (null) (null)    (null)   2  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     cats       eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY  4       a.id     1  
2   DERIVED     cats       ALL     (null)          (null) (null)    (null)   6  Using filesort
```

and adding index will make it faster

Comment: is there any way to remove the subquery and still have a single query?

Comment: @CarlosP Not any reliable way.  There are some tricks with indexes that will almost always work if you're careful.

Comment: Do you have to used two `*`? This query would combine both data sets. In that case yo would only have to get the id in the inner join query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT * FROM `cats` c
JOIN (
    SELECT `war_id`, `n_of_medals`, MAX(`date_last_fought`) date_last_fought
    FROM `cats` 
    WHERE `war_id` = 0 
    AND `eyes_color` = 'green' 
    GROUP BY `war_id`, `n_of_medals` 
) c_summary ON c_summary.war_id = c.war_id
AND c_summary.n_of_medals = c.n_of_medals 
AND c_summary.date_last_fought = c.date_last_fought
ORDER BY c.`date_last_fought` DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05bcb/2